# Is there any ways to copy all file to one specific sub-folder under the same parent-folder?

Tags: shell, files, file-copy

So for example i have one folder called "test". Inside that folder, i created one another folder called "player" and a lot of text file, let's say 50 files.

```
[root@ip-10-0-7-70 test]# ls
kaka.txt  player  rooney.txt
```

Now i want to move all of that text file into "player" folder. What's the best way to do this?

I tried

```
cp -r ls | ^egrep 'player'
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `test` directory, do:

```
mv -t player *.txt
```

Assuming all text files end in `.txt`.

This will `mv` all `.txt` files from current directory (`test/`) to `player/` subdirectory.